# 2 separate unique constraints in the same class

Tags: doctrine

How can I add 2 separate unique constraints in the same table/class?
I have this:

```
@ORM\Table(name="test", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique_code", columns={"code"})})
```

Something like this:

```
 @ORM\Table(name="test", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique_code", columns={"code"}, name="unique_value", columns={"value"})})
```

I don't want to unificate them. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the unique constraint on the class you can make each column unique by adding that option to the column definition:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class MyEntity
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(unique=true)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(unique=true)
     */
    private $value;
}
```

Setting the unique constraint on the class is mostly useful when you want to make a combination of fields unique, i.e. a certain combination of code and value can only occur once.

Alternatively you can provide multiple constraints in the list:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     uniqueConstraints={
 *         @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique_code", columns={"code"}),
 *         @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique_value", columns={"value"})
 *     }
 * )
 */
class MyEntity { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, that was the thing.